# Trobule loading JSON data with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I open my JSON file in the browser and put this into the console:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for(i=0; i < p.length; i++) {

  var data = JSON.parse(p[i].innerHTML);
  var pc = data.postalcodes;


    for (var key in pc) {
                if (key == "800") {
                    alert("Postcode:" + key + ", name: " + pc[key].name);
                }
            }
}
```

It works fine.

Now I just want to do the same put have to load the JSON file. I have made this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#postcode").focusout(function() {

      $.getJSON("postnr.json", function(json) {
            var data = json;
            var pc = data.postalcodes;
            for (var key in pc) {
                if (key == "800") {
                    alert(key + "yes" + pc[key].name);
                }
            }

        });

    });

})
</script>
```

But nothing happens on focusout and I think it is because the JSON is not loaded. Why is it not loaded?

Comment: why the loop+key test? a simple `if (pc['800']) { alert(...) }` would do just as well.

Comment: Have you actually tried printing out/looking the response?

Comment: Add an error handler and log the arguments.

Comment: How to check if the JSON gets loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this line says that it will only be loaded after the element #postalcode is unfocused:

```
$("#postcode").focusout(function() {
```

So I would remove that and leave only this for debugging:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("postnr.json", function(json) {
    alert("postnr.json has been loaded");
  })
  .error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("error: " + errorThrown);
  });
});
```

If you get the error then check from there.

Comment: Should I provide the full path?

Comment: Think I have found the problem

Comment: The file was txt instead of JSON -.-